# Whats the alternative to “exclude” command of rpm.spec file in debian package building

Tags: debian, rpmbuild, pkgbuild

While building an rpm package we can use this exclude command in the spec file to exclude the particular file in certain packages.

ex.

```
%exclude foobar/bin/printjob_svr.bin
```

How and where do we specify the same while building a deb package? I have a list of files that need to be excluded while building different packages from the source. Right now I am able to build three different packages from the source but all the files are present while installation.

Answer (score 1):

In a Debian package, you’d do this either by deleting the files after installation (in the source package) but before the package is built, or by not listing them in the lists of files to install, or by excluding them from the installation (for certain types of files only).

If you’re using short-style `dh`-based `debian/rules`, you’ll probably be using (implicitly)

- `dh_auto_install`, which runs the upstream installation to place files in `debian/tmp` (since you’re building multiple packages);
- `dh_install`, which copies files from `debian/tmp` to the appropriate installation target (`debian/foobar` etc.) based on the contents of `.install` files in `debian` (`debian/foobar.install` etc.).

The three options listed above translate to the following.

1. To delete files after they’re copied to `debian/tmp`, do something like

   ```
   override_dh_intall:
           rm -f debian/tmp/bin/printjob_svr.bin
           dh_install
   ```
2. To tell `dh_install` to skip files, don’t list them in `.install` files; that means you can’t use wildcards or plain directory names (`bin`, `bin/*`). You should also list the skipped files in `debian/not-installed`, but see the caveat in `man dh_missing`.
3. To exclude files explicitly, override the targets and add `-X` options; this will only work for `dh_` commands which support this:

   ```
   override_dh_installdocs:
           dh_installdocs -Xprintjob_svr.bin
   ```

   (this doesn’t correspond to your use-case, I’m listing it for completeness).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your awesome reply, I had already tried methods 1 and 2. Using `.install` file seems to be the easiest as i can find which files to exclude from `debian/tmp` (I already have a spec file in place). However I was looking for perhaps an easier method to do this rather than running a script to create `.install` files for all my packages.